# Can't call void android.view.View.setTranslationZ(float) on null object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, samsung-mobile

I am using library recyclerview-multiselect in my project to select multiple items on recyclerview
On samsung device:
When I longpress and select a item the multiselector starts but as soon as I deselect the last selected item I get following exception
This is happening only om samsung devices

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.view.View.setTranslationZ(float) on null object
in call to CallVoidMethodV
from void android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(java.lang.Object, long, float)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x86d99ef0 self=0xb4d07800
| sysTid=28321 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f9dec8
| state=R schedstat=( 1263638622 186444747 1521 ) utm=90 stm=36 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0xbe20a000-0xbe20c000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
native: #00 pc 00004c58  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
native: #01 pc 000034c1  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
native: #02 pc 002590fd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
native: #03 pc 0023c5c3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+162)
native: #04 pc 000b2655  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+620)
native: #05 pc 000b2d85  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
native: #06 pc 000b309f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckVirtualMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*)+438)
native: #07 pc 000be40b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+82)
native: #08 pc 00068467  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
native: #09 pc 00072005  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_animation_PropertyValuesHolder_nCallFloatMethod__Ljava_lang_Object_2JF+132)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(Native method)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1296)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:952)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1207)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1248)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:659)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:682)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
```

Comment: I am getting the same crash when calling setStateListAnimator() on my Button. It is happening on my Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: We had the same problem when we called setStateListAnimator(null); on a View.

Comment: @hellphil I already tried that, I am using recyclerview, on which view did u do that ?
any more suggestions ??

Comment: I am getting the same crash as @rrbrambley but it happens when i set `android:enabled="false"` on my Button in xml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I was using recycleview-multiselect, it has setSelectionModeStateListAnimator,setDefaultModeStateListAnimator, setSelectionModeBackgroundDrawable,setDefaultModeBackgroundDrawable set in SwappingHolder
So after my super call to holder just set:

```
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setSelectionModeStateListAnimator(null);
        setDefaultModeStateListAnimator(null);
    }
    // Default selection mode background drawable is this
    setSelectionModeBackgroundDrawable(null);
    setDefaultModeBackgroundDrawable( null );
```

And used my own selectors in xml, this has resolved the crash.

Comment: Please post some sample code of your selectors, how they looked, and perhaps how you implemented them. This will be very beneficial to the rising Samsung Lollipop community.

Comment: I also use recycleview-multiselect and this happens after I long-click on some item for few seconds. Note that it is OK in emulator. @chin87, could you give some more info, please?

Comment: @WindRider have you used ViewHolder ?
In ViewHolders constructor, after super call add the above code

Comment: I had the same problem, thank for the fix. you saved me hours of debuging

Answer (score 0):

Turning a comment on the question, by Etienne Lawlor, into an answer:

> I am getting the same crash as @rrbrambley but it happens when i set `android:enabled="false"` on my Button in xml.

I verified that changing `android:enabled="false"` to `android:enabled="true"` solves this problem at least in my case.

Comment: I turned this (formally) into an answer. I hope that it technically (where I lack knowledge) actually an answer to the question at the top of the page. Please review and if you do not  think that this either is or you can [edit] this into an answer according to [answer] then please delete this post.